# Editing text on a http server hosted by esp8266

Tags: c#, esp8266, simplehttpserver

I have a simple http server hosted by an esp8266. I want to be able to write text to the web page that is displayed.  However, I can't find an example of how to do this. Thanks for the help, just getting started with programming so apologies if this cant be done. I'm really clutching at straws.

Comment: Hello @CrazyGreninja, it would be easier for community to help you if you'd provide code that you already have.

Comment: Maybe this can help you [https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server-with-arduino-ide/](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/esp8266-web-server-with-arduino-ide/)

Comment: Something like this https://www.intertech.com/Blog/iot-with-an-esp8266-part-3-aspnet-core-project-and-database-setup/?